# Google taking my logo as title and description some text on the page

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, googlebot, search-engines

I made a website using nuxt.js and added title and meta description on each page. I also made a sitemap.xml and robots.txt for the site and submitted in Google search console.The issue is Google and other search engines are taking some random text on the page and title as the logo on the page. It tried different website to check what is exactly being crawled like metatags.io it is showing the correct result which I desire

But still whenever I search I get this in the search result

I tried to recrawl the website in the Google search console still stuck with this issue. Is there anything I am missing??

Comment: If you don't use your brand name in your title, Google will completely ignore the title tag you have written.

Answer (score 1):

Google will not always pick the user-created titles and descriptions. Google generates titles in snippets based on page content and relevance to search queries.

Ref: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/appearance/good-titles-snippets#why-the-search-result-title-might-differ-from-the-pages-title-tag

> Sometimes even pages with well-formulated, concise,
> descriptive titles will end up with different titles in our search
> results to better indicate their relevance to the query. There's a
> simple reason for this: the title tag as specified by a website owner
> is limited to being static, fixed regardless of the query.

The same logic holds good for descriptions as well.

Google may or may not pick meta descriptions. It can pick any text from the page that it thinks is relevant to the user's query. Here is a quote from the same official page:

> Google **sometimes** uses `<meta>` tag content to generate snippets, if we
> think they give users a more accurate description than can be taken
> directly from the page content.