# Why different title on the same website

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engines, meta-tags

I have recently changed the title of my website and whenever I search it I get the previous one only

but on search with the specific keywords change I have recently made I get the correct output which I have changed

Why is that and will I get punished for this? And is it possible to remove the old one and replace it with the new one

Comment: The answer is the same for your previous question (https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/135841/google-taking-my-logo-as-title-and-description-some-text-on-the-page) and this one. Google can pick or leave a user-created title. It chooses what to display based on query relevance. And, there is no question of getting punished as this is normal behavior.